# beforeUpdate not called when only transients has changed

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I use Grails 2.0.0.RC2 and I have an User class like this:

```
class User {
    String username
    String password

    // Idea from http://grailsrecipes.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/grails-user-registration-and-login/ .
    String formPassword
    String formPasswordConfirm

    // Constraints and validation ommited

    static transients = ['formPassword', 'formPasswordConfirm']

    def beforeUpdate() {
        println("Inside beforeUpdate")
        if (formPassword != null)
            encodePassword()
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = formPassword // Just for this case
    }
}
```

When user asks for his password reset, I send him email with a link to reset password page. Reset password form is simple - it contains only two fields: `formPassword` and `formPasswordConfirm`. I do a simple action in controller: `user.formPassword = params["formPassword"]` and `user.formPasswordConfirm = params["formPasswordConfirm"]`. Then I do (`user.save()`) - and problem begins.

My problem is that `beforeUpdate()` is not called. I thought it was a validation problem (it's omiited here), but it's not. As it turns out `user.save()` didn't persist user to database! Why? I wanted it to be persisted, password should be changed. But `user.isDirty()` is false just before `user.save()`. That's because none of persistent properties were changed. That's true. Since `user.save()` wasn't called - `beforeUpdate()` wasn't called either.

Is this desired behaviour? Maybe it's a Grails bug and `beforeUpdate()` should be always called before update and then `isDirty()` should be checked? What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if `beforeUpdate` should be called when transient fields are updated, but given the choice between

1. it's a Grails/Hibernate bug
2. this is the expected behaviour because no DB updates would happen when transient fields are modified

I would bet a lot of money on 2, and very little on 1.

So leaving that aside, I think you've made your domain class a bit more complicated that it needs to be. Specifically, you should be able to achieve your goal with 2 password fields instead of 3.

```
class User {

    static transients = ['passwordConfirm']
    def springSecurityService

    String password
    String passwordConfirm

    static constraints = {
        password blank: false, validator: {password, self ->

            // We only need to check the password confirmation when it is not empty, i.e.
            // when a user registers or resets their password
            if (self.passwordConfirm) {
                password == self.passwordConfirm
            }
        }
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    private void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
        passwordConfirm = springSecurityService.encodePassword(passwordConfirm)
    }

}
```

Your reset password controller action should look like this:

```
def resetPassword = {

    User user = User.findByUsername(params.username)
    user.password = params.formPassword
    user.passwordConfirm = params.formPasswordConfirm

    if (user.save()) {
        // It worked, send them to the login page or whatever...
    } else {
        // Validation failed, send them back to the reset password page    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I like your solution with 2 password fields. It solves beforeUpdate not being called too. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. This is almost identical to the solution in my own application (which also uses spring security), and it works well

Comment: but I still need to resolve one more problem. After validation phase how do you ecnode password that gets stored to db? In Grails 2.0.0.RC2 beforeUpdate occurs before validation.

Comment: @TomaszKalkosiński I've updated my code above to show how I do password encoding

Comment: Nice, I thought about encoding passwordConfirm before validation too after I've asked you.

Answer (score 2):

This is desired behavior.

The semantics are pretty crystal clear in my opinion, you have not changed any persistent fields, ergo there is nothing to save. The .save() has no way of guessing that in this case some transient property should make you run through the save() (and then beforeUpdate()).

Just add a method that updates the password and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not so easy with a method that updates the password. I rely on a password validation during validation phase, that's why encodePassword() is called in beforeUpdate().